# How to show an Image gradually within the ScrollView?

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview, android-scrollview

Is there any process to increase the height of ScrollView gradually at run time. My intention is to show an image gradually which is within the ScrollView.So I want to increase the height of ScrollView. Is there any way to do my job?? Please help me out.Content of my XmlFile is :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

my code is :

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() {

                    secondCounter++;
                    yourNewHeight += 10;
                    // sv is object of scroll view
                    sv.getLayoutParams().height = yourNewHeight;

                    root.invalidate(); // root is rootview


                    if(secondCounter == 20){
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, delay, period);
```

Here is my screen shot:

[image]

the blurred image is with in the Scrollview and as height of ScrollView increasing the blurred image is showing gradually.

Comment: r u adding more than on image programatically??

Comment: no. only one image which is already with in the scrollView.

Comment: pls clear to me what you want to show.if there is only one image than why u r adding inside scrollview??

Comment: Use [`setLayoutParams(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)) in your code to set the width and height programmatically.

Comment: hmm....!!! there is only one image. And my intention is to increase height of scrollView gradually such that the image with in it can be shown.. wait im posting some screen shot here..!!!

Comment: dont give static height to scroll view.it will show according to the height of the imagview

Comment: here is my screenshot..is it clear now ??

Comment: u have taken scrollview for what purpose??

Comment: because ..scroll view don't compress image..it shows as the image is.

Comment: set background of imageview.it will show actual image

Comment: in screen shot there is 2 image view.one is normal(which is in background) and another one is blurred and within the scroll view..!! so when i increase the height of scroll view then a scanning effect occurs.

Comment: can u pls give me two images with actual sizes so that i can try?? and u want to show this image in whole screen or there are any other contents in the screens??

Comment: http://i49.tinypic.com/4ux4i1.png <--- the normal image.  http://i46.tinypic.com/2qi7cec.png <--- the blurred image.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width=" fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/background" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

let me know have done with this or not .. ok..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`setLayoutParams(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) to set your width and height programmatically. Check out the question *mao* gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805261/android-programmatically-specify-height-and-width-of-new-scrollview) and the solutions.

Comment: height of scroll view will not be fixed.it will be increased periodically.